# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION breakpoint when starting app xCode

Tags: uitableview, swift

I have a tableview in my app and when I start my app it crashes on the following function.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    // Configure the cell...
    let cellId: NSString = "Cell"
    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId) as UITableViewCell
}
```

It crashes on the line of `var cell`

It gives the following error: 
[image: error]

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

The whole function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    // Configure the cell...
    let cellId: NSString = "Cell"
    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId) as UITableViewCell

    let data: NSManagedObject = mylist[ip.row] as NSManagedObject

    cell.textLabel.text = data.valueForKeyPath("voornaam") as String
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = data.valueForKeyPath("achternaam") as String
    return cell
}
```

**EDIT**:
What I got now:(Still gives the same error)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell? {
    // Configure the cell...
    let cellId: NSString = "Cell"
    var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId) as? UITableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

    let data: NSManagedObject = mylist[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject

    cell!.textLabel.text = data.valueForKey("voornaam") as String
    cell!.detailTextLabel.text = data.valueForKey("achternaam") as String
    //cell!.textLabel.text = "Hoi"
    return cell
}
```

Comment: 2 ideas: First of all, try cleaning your project (cmd + shift + k). If that doesn't work, try taking a look at [breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints.html) Remove any if you have them.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the `as` operator is defined to cast an object to a given type and crash if the conversion fails. In this case, the call to `dequeue` returns `nil` the first time you call it. You need to use the `as?` operator, which will attempt to cast the given object to a type, and return an optional that has a value only if the conversion succeeded:

```
var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId) as? UITableViewCell

if cell == nil {
  cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
}

...
```

Because `cell` is now an optional value, use `cell!` when you want to call methods on it to force-unwrap the `UITableViewCell` inside it.

Additionally, your code had a second problem: it never created a fresh cell. `dequeue` will return nil the first time it's called on your table view. You need to instantiate a new `UITableViewCell` as in my code sample and then return it from the `cellFor...` method. The table view will then save the cell and return it on future calls to `dequeue`.

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` always returns a cell if it's set up correctly. The documentation says: "This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one using the class or nib file you previously registered. If no cell is available for reuse and you did not register a class or nib file, this method returns nil." You had to manually check and create the cell before iOS 6 I think.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried your solution, but I unfortunately get the same error.

Comment: @Bas Is it still crashing on the same line, or is it different now? Swift is a much stricter language than Objective-C, so one of your other `as` invocations could be causing the problem.

Comment: @E.Parto When you say "always", what you mean is "in certain circumstances."

Comment: @Bill yes it's still crashing on the same line.

Comment: @Bill "Always" means that your `if cell == nil` block never gets executed if you setup your TableView correctly and you can remove them in your refactors. The header file has this comment on `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` “`// newer dequeue method **guarantees** a cell is returned and resized properly, assuming identifier is registered`”. The only scenario when this method can return nil is if you try to dequeue a cell but you haven’t registered a class or a nib or you don’t have a prototype cell in IB with that identifier. That’s what I call setting it up incorrectly.

Comment: @Bill when you don't want to touch IB and want to do everything programmatically, it's better to create a class and register it for that identifier. It's paying attention to Separation of Concerns as a design principle. I’d stick to the old way only when I want to create a plain, non-custom cell that can be created with one line and has no design logic at all.

Comment: An it's fairly common to just need to fill in a base UITableViewCell in `cellForIndexPath`. My point is that it's possible (and common) to have an entirely "correct setup" where `dequeue` returns nil.

Answer (score 0):

First off, why are you doing an optional binding on line `if let ip = indexPath`? This argument is not optional and you don't need to do optional binding or unwrap it. But this shouldn't cause your code to crash.

Remove your `let data` line and assign literal strings to your cells and see if it still crashes.

Comment: I first had it optional, but indeed I don't need the optional binding

Comment: if i assign literal strings it doesn't crash anymore and also deleted the optional binding

Comment: Why are you using `valueForKeyPath` instead of `valueForKey`?

Comment: Not a reason, I thought they do basically the same. But changing that doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Your ViewController seems okay. I'd check `mylist` and most probably your Core Data setup, model or entities. You can update your question with more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help:) I will update my question tomorrow, I'm not at my laptop right now it's 02:30 AM here:)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you check to see if you set the tableview's delegates? I made that mistake once in the flurry of setting everything else up.

Comment: Tableview delegates and datasource are set!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is too late but I like to share my experience. I had similar error as I copied the entire code from another project. So I think the variables and functions won't be recognised so I had to drag them (cntr+drag) then it is solved. 
Sorry if I couldn't explain better. I am new this.